# How can I complete a JS action based on the presence of a cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, js-cookie

I am working on a form and when you focus on an input field, I have a pop up that reminds them to save when they are complete. I only want the user to see this pop up once every 60 days. On focus I set a cookie that tells me they have seen the alert. Then however, since I only want this to appear every 60 days, I want to make sure it doesn't happen again next time they click. How do I execute something like, "if this cookie exists, then do this?" Below is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
//My alert goes here (i'm good on this part")
Cookies.set('saveChanges', 'wasAlerted', { expires: 60, path: '/' });
//if SOMETHING, do SOMETHING ("need help here")
});
```

FYI, My cookie name is 'saveChanges' and the value is 'wasAlerted'.

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as the value of the cookie is redundant, you can just check if there's a cookie matching `saveChanges`.

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    if (Cookies.get('saveChanges') == null) {
        //Alert
        Cookies.set('saveChanges', 'wasAlerted', { expires: 60, path: '/' });
    }
}
```

Side note, I'd recommend using the [jQuery Cookie Plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) for organization's sake. The API is not too much different but it will make your code more consistent.

Comment: @ColtonBlake, please do not recommend and outdated version. JavaScript Cookie IS jQuery Cookie, just without the jQuery dependency and with a clearer API that express intent. See [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/issues/349).